# How to make the computer speak in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtts

I tried to use gtts:

```
from gtts import gTTs
import os

tts = gTTS(text='Good morning', lang='en')
tts.save("good.mp3")
os.system("mpg321 good.mp3")
```

But I got this error:

```
'mpg321' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.
```

Why does this happen? I even have portaudio but do not know how to do it.

Comment: Does `mpg321 good.mp3` work *outside* Python?

Comment: also try to add the path to mpg321. Often PATH environment variables are not available within system commands.

Comment: i did add mpg to path, there is no nice website to download it too.

Comment: What do you mean outside python

Comment: do you use Linux ? On Linux Ubuntu/Mint/Debian you can install it with `apt install mpg321`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mpg is a complex way to make the computer speak

tried to use playsound its easy to install via pip and isn't so complicated.
all you have to do is type in

```
playsound("good.mp3")
```

Comment: I even used os. Its syntax is ` os.system("Start example.mp3") `.